# Need to pass metadata as json. Paystack

Tags: php, arrays, json, payment-gateway, webhooks

I started using [paystack](https://paystack.com/docs/api) recently and it's similar to stripe but I'm having problem passing in [metadata](https://paystack.com/docs/payments/metadata/#crafting-metadata). I do not know if I'm correct or not because I've not been able to make reference to it from my [webhook url](https://paystack.com/docs/payments/webhooks/#what-are-webhooks). I have added it to my dashboard as instructed although I am told :

> "If using .htaccess, remember to add the trailing / to the url you set."

Which I don't fully understand(I'm using .htaccess). For instance if I have a webhook of [www.example.com/webhook](https://paystack.com/docs/api), am I supposed to add another / at the end or what?

To continue... I need to pass in the metadata which would look something like this at the end...

```
     {
  "event": "subscription.create",
  "data": {
    "domain": "test",
    "status": "active",
    "subscription_code": "SUB_vsyqdmlzble3uii",
    "amount": 50000,
    "cron_expression": "0 0 28 * *",
    "next_payment_date": "2016-05-19T07:00:00.000Z",
    "open_invoice": null,
    "createdAt": "2016-03-20T00:23:24.000Z",
    "plan": {
      "name": "Monthly retainer",
      "plan_code": "PLN_gx2wn530m0i3w3m",
      "description": null,
      "amount": 50000,
      "interval": "monthly",
      "send_invoices": true,
      "send_sms": true,
    },
    "authorization": {
      "authorization_code": "AUTH_96xphygz",
      "bin": "539983",
      "last4": "7357",
      "exp_month": "10",
      "exp_year": "2017",
      "card_type": "MASTERCARD DEBIT",
      "bank": "GTBANK",
      "country_code": "NG",
      "brand": "MASTERCARD",
      "account_name": "BoJack Horseman"
    },
    "customer": {
      "first_name": "BoJack",
      "last_name": "Horseman",
      "email": "bojack@horsinaround.com",
      "customer_code": "CUS_xnxdt6s1zg1f4nx",
      "phone": "",
      "metadata": {},
      "risk_action": "default"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-10-01T10:59:59.000Z"
  }
}
```

On my php script I added metadata fields like this:

```
    <?php
      $url = "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/initialize";
$access = $_POST['access'];
$support = $_POST['support'];
      $fields = [
        'email' => "customer@email.com",
        'amount' => "20000",
    'metadata' => [
          'access' => $access,
          'support' => $support,
        ]
      ];
      $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
      //open connection
      $ch = curl_init();
      
      //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Authorization: Bearer SECRET_KEY",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
      ));
      
      //So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
      
      //execute post
     if ($result) {
        $authorization_data = json_decode($result);
        $authorization_url = $authorization_data->data->authorization_url;
        header("Location: ".$authorization_url);
        exit();
      }
    ?>
```

On my webhook url.. I recieve the response then decode it(`$event = json_decode(inputrecieved)`). I try to recieve it as:

```
$support = $event->customer->metadata->support;
```

But not sure if the way I sent it, it can be accessed this way.

Answer (score 0):

If your receiving end is expecting a json as the body, you need to send it as a json--by building up the payload and just json_encode it.

Prepping data:

```
//break it out to make it easier on yourself
$customerMetaData = [ ..., 'support' => 'abc' ];
$customer = [ 'email' => ..., 'metadata' => $customerMetaData  ];
$payload = ['customer' => $customer];
$jsonString = json_encode($payload);
...
//add Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8 to HTTPHEADER array

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonString);
```

Receiving end:

```
$eventJson = file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = json_decode($eventJson);
$support = $event->customer->metadata->support;
```

Comment: It's encoded automatically. It's passed through some http_build_query. If I encode it, I don't even get sent to the payment page. I can recieve every other thing fine except the metadata. Every thing seems to be empty in the metadata.

Comment: In your code above, you set $fields = [... 'metadata' => ..] and youre accessing it via $event->customer->metadata->support; it needs to be $fields = [... 'customer' => [ 'metadata' => [..] ] ]

Comment: http_build_query turns things into form data: a=1&b=2&c=3&d=3 ; u cant json_decode that;  so u need to json_encode before sending instead of http_build_query

Comment: Did you later fix this, please I need help with this now?